# How can I remove [:b (lvar)] from [[:a :A] [:b :B] [:c :C]] in Clojure core.logic?

Tags: clojure, logic, clojure-core.logic

I want to remove `[:b :B]` from `[[:a :A] [:b :B] [:c :C]]` in the following example code, and if I replace `:B` with `(lvar)`, it no longer works:

```
;; Helper Function
(defne not-membero [x l]
  ([_ []])
  ([_ [?y . ?r]]
   (!= x ?y)
   (not-membero x ?r)))
```

These work:

```
(run* [q]
  (membero q [[:a :A] [:b :B] [:c :C]])
  (not-membero q [[:b :B]]))
(run* [q]
  (membero q [[:a :A] [:b :B] [:c :C]])
  (!= q [:b :B]))
;; both return [[:a :A] [:c :C]], as expected
```

These do not (notice the `lvar`):

```
(run* [q]
  (membero q [[:a :A] [:b :B] [:c :C]])
  (not-membero q [[:b (lvar)]]))
(run* [q]
  (membero q [[:a :A] [:b :B] [:c :C]])
  (!= q [:b (lvar)]))
;; both return [[:a :A] [:b :B] [:c :C]], unexpected
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the reason this doesn't work in your example is that the created `(lvar)` is unbound/unrelated to any other logic variable in the program. Your program works fine (at least I think this is what you wanted) if you use a `fresh` logic variable:

```
(run* [q]
  (fresh [x]
    (membero q [[:a :A] [:b x] [:c :C]])
    (not-membero q [[:b x]])))
=> ([:a :A] [:c :C])
(run* [q]
  (fresh [x]
    (membero q [[:a :A] [:b x] [:c :C]])
    (!= q [:b x])))
=> ([:a :A] [:c :C])
```

Alternatively, these return the same result without knowledge of the `:b` item in the tuple:

```
(run* [q]
  (fresh [x]
    (membero q [[:a :A] x [:c :C]])
    (not-membero q [x])))
(run* [q]
  (fresh [x]
    (membero q [[:a :A] x [:c :C]])
    (!= q x)))
```